# How to assert a string having special chars in it?

Tags: karate

- def errorMessage = 'Client version is invalid. The client version cannot contain any of the following characters: \"&'(),/:;<>\'
- def expectedMessage = 'Client version is invalid. The client version cannot contain any of the following characters: \"&'(),/:;<>\'

Then match errorMessage contains expectedMessage .

Since my error message and expected message has special characters in it assertion is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have escape few special characters like single and double quotes,

```
# Client version is invalid. The client version cannot contain any of the following characters: \"&'(),/:;<>
* def errorMessage = 'Client version is invalid. The client version cannot contain any of the following characters: \\"&\'(),/:;<>'
* def expectedMessage = 'Client version is invalid. The client version cannot contain any of the following characters: \\"&\'(),/:;<>'
* match errorMessage == expectedMessage
```

Comment: Thank you Babu. Working perfectly fine . Quick and accurate as before :)